# How to use Backpack for Laravel on existing project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm building a small app with Laravel and I just discovered Backpack that looks very nice !

I downloaded it (I have a license), but I really don't know how to use it with my existing files (so far 3 controllers, 3 models and a few blade files)

Maybe the answer is somewhere in the documentation, but I could not find it..

A detailed explanation would help.

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have model called Person ...

```
php artisan backpack:crud Person
```

the generated command will tell you that the model is existed... and it will generate the routes and Crud Controller for you ...

then you go to your model ... in 'use' section add:

```
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
```

and in your model body ... add

```
 use CrudTrait;
```

you can also override the views ... witch i do not recommend unless you have good reason for that

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/upgrade-guide#views

Comment: Thank you OMR. That was pretty easy ;) I just have to explore more Backpack now. Thanks again !

Comment: I agree with the above. I would mention that starting with May 2020 the generators will add the CrudTrait on the existing model for you, so you no longer have to manually do that.

Comment: This also seems to solve a problem adding a CrudTrait. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943908/problem-adding-crudtrait-to-existing-model/63002985#63002985