# Problem adding CrudTrait to existing Model

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-backpack

Problem using Backpack to do its thing (automate adding its features) to the project.

**From the [tutorial](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/getting-started-videos):**

[image]

**Mine:**

```
PS C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern>  php artisan blueprint:build 
...
PS C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern> php artisan backpack:crud Product     
Controller created successfully.

   ErrorException 

  Undefined variable: position

  at C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern\vendor\backpack\generators\src\Console\Commands\CrudModelBackpackCommand.php:94
    90|                     // the same as the array index - arrays start counting from 0,
    91|                     // IDEs start counting from 1
    92| 
    93|                     // add CrudTrait
  > 94|                     array_splice($file_array, $position, 0, '    use \\'.$this->crudTrait.';');
    95| 
    96|                     // save the file
    97|                     $this->files->put($path, implode(PHP_EOL, $file_array));
    98| 

  1   C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern\vendor\backpack\generators\src\Console\Commands\CrudModelBackpackCommand.php:94
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined variable: position", "C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern\vendor\backpack\generators\src\Console\Commands\CrudModelBackpackCommand.php")

  2   C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:33     
      Backpack\Generators\Console\Commands\CrudModelBackpackCommand::handle()
PS C:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\cofour-intern>
```

Comment: no obvious reason, please try: php artisan backpack:crud product ('with samll p');

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the before command content and after command content of the class in question. Off hand, it seems like something is missing from the class that the command expects to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out the automated adding of CrudTrait, and then adding it manually as recommended by @OMR [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116088/how-to-use-backpack-for-laravel-on-existing-project), works. Presumably should not be necessary, but now the command calls work in the regular order:

```
blueprint:build
backpack:build
```

**CrudModelBackpackCommand.php (line 75):**

```
        // if it does not have CrudTrait, add the trait on the Model

        $classDefinition = 'class '.$this->getNameInput().' extends';

        // foreach ($file_array as $key => $line) {
        //     if (Str::contains($line, $classDefinition)) {
        //         if (Str::endsWith($line, '{')) {
        //             // add the trait on the next
        //             $position = $key + 1;
        //         } elseif ($file_array[$key + 1] == '{') {
        //             // add the trait on the next next line
        //             $position = $key + 2;
        //         }

        //         // keep in mind that the line number shown in IDEs is not
        //         // the same as the array index - arrays start counting from 0,
        //         // IDEs start counting from 1

        //         // add CrudTrait
        //         array_splice($file_array, $position, 0, '    use \\'.$this->crudTrait.';');

        //         // save the file
        //         $this->files->put($path, implode(PHP_EOL, $file_array));

        //         // let the user know what we've done
        //         $this->info('Model already exists! We just added CrudTrait on it.');

        //         return false;
        //     }
        // }

        $this->error('Model already exists! Could not add CrudTrait - please add manually.');

        return false;
    }
```

I likely moved some file out of place, but I am not sure which one...

The case has also been opened as a bug on their github [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Generators/issues/95#issuecomment-664045611).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the your model and in use section add:

```
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
```

and in model body section add:

```
use CrudTrait;
```

It's should work.